# Visual Composer - Overwrite class

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress website using Visual Composer (WPBakery).

I had to modify some classes in the core of the plugin, for example,

I modified this class : **WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section**

The problem is I had to modify functions in the core of the plugin (shortcodes/vc-tta-section.php).

I didn't found any solution to overwrite a class of Visual Composer. Even If I extends this class and add my own code, I would have to call my own class, but didn't found anything in the code that could help me to modify base class used **WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section** to **WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section_CUSTOM** for example.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why you need to modify the class? That is not a good way to modify the plugin.

Comment: @tristup I needed to add a tab on each accordion with a specific class. And needed to change the tab_id with the title of the accordion instead of the random numbers/letters

Comment: I think there are two boxes are already there in accordian section, please check the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/18l9JRmIq3EoWUvwGTDjTzqhzVm93VY1-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tristup I mean, add a tab on EACH accordion with a certain class on the accordion. Without the needs to set it up on each pages (there is more than 50 pages with that. So I don't really want to change EACH pages if client have to change a thing in the tab, you see ?)

Comment: Where are you attempting to extend **WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section** ?

Comment: @Jamie_D What do you mean ? If I understand well, I'm just modifying some methods in the class

Comment: Did you try extending the class in your functions.php file?  :  "The function can be called by extending the class WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section. It can be called either using the html overriding process or via your child theme functions.php" ... from:  [link]https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431/comments?page=892

Comment: @Jamie_D Ok, that seems to be the solution. So there is a solution. But how do I make an instance of my new class extending WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section instead of WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section ? I made a WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section_Custom with the change on the methods I need, but I don't see how to instance this one instead of WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Tta_Section